# Is there a better way than this to split a string and get the first substring?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, string-manipulation

I'm trying to cut off everything after a certain character (in this case '&') and if there is no occurence of that character, get the entire string.

```
select left(@str,isnull(nullif(charindex('&',@str) - 1,-1),len(@str)))
```

This seems to be a rather needlessly complicated way of doing it.   Is there a better/shorter way?

Here is a full test case to indicate what I'm doing...

```
declare @str as varchar(255) 
set @str = 'abc&def&ghi'

select left(@str,isnull(nullif(charindex('&',@str) - 1,-1),len(@str)))

-- Returns 'abc'

set @str = 'abc'

select left(@str,isnull(nullif(charindex('&',@str) - 1,-1),len(@str)))

-- Returns 'abc'
```

Comment: What is the end result you are you trying to achieve? Is this for a report? Legacy  migration? I would be a bit concerned if you are developing an app today on 2005.

Comment: Do you need to do this in a single statement? On the fly?

Comment: Can you upgrade the db?

Comment: The end result is to cut off everything after '&' from a certain field.   I need to do it in a single statement.    I cannot upgrade the db.

Comment: I'm just asking for the sake of education.  In the actual use-case I will just use what I've done here.  But I wondered if there's a better way because it seems overkill to use five functions for a fairly simple process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - here is 'another' way...

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(255)

SET @str = 'abc&def&ghi'

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN charindex('&', @str) > 0
            THEN substring(@str, 1, charindex('&', @str) - 1)
        ELSE @str
        END AS SelectedString
-------------------------------
SET @str = 'abc'

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN charindex('&', @str) > 0
            THEN substring(@str, 1, charindex('&', @str) - 1)
        ELSE @str
        END AS SelectedString
```

**OR - you could simply ALWAYS concatenate '&' at the end of the string like this:**

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(255)

SET @str = 'abc&def&ghi'

SELECT substring(@str, 1, charindex('&', @str + '&') - 1)
-------------------------------
SET @str = 'abc'

SELECT substring(@str, 1, charindex('&', @str + '&') - 1)
```